# Getting karate-config.js failed for mac and Linux where as it works well for windows

Tags: java, automation, karate

karate-config.js failed
TypeError: Access to host class Ritam.Util.PropertyLoader is not allowed or does not exist.

This works completely well when running on windows
Java_Version:20

[INFO] Running Ritam.TestRunners.TestRunnerParallel
20:32:40.784 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - using system property 'karate.env': QA
20:32:42.176 [main] WARN  com.intuit.karate.Suite - failed to backup existing dir: target
Platform is lambdatest
OS is windows
Env is QA
Browser is chrome